# Newest date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Hy, how can I get the newest date with this statement?

```
"SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB EVP_1 WHERE 
EVP_1.OIB_OSIGURANIK = ? 
AND DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (SELECT MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM 
EVP_V_KASKO_ZB"
WHERE OIB_OSIGURANIK = EVP_1.OIB_OSIGURANIK)";
```

DATUM_OSIGURANJA is date parametar and the result is not newest date, but the date with max number value.. confusing..
how to solve that?

```
20.06.2014
16.06.2018
11.06.2017
20.06.2015
```

this is the rows to compare

and this is my result

```
20.06.2015
```

Comment: How is stored the date? a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `DATUM_OSIGURANJA` is a `VARCHAR2` column; is it? If so, you'll have to convert it to a `DATE` and then select its `MAX` value. Something like this:

```
SELECT e.model, e.v_godina, e.datum_osiguranja
  FROM evp_v_kasko_zb e
 WHERE     e.oib_osiguranik = '99999999994'      --> guess what? A valid OIB :)
       AND TO_DATE (e.datum_osiguranja, 'dd.mm.yyyy') =
              (SELECT MAX (TO_DATE (e1.datum_osiguranja, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
                 FROM evp_v_kasko_zb e1
                WHERE e1.oib_osiguranik = e.oib_osiguranik);
```

Note that it will *ruin* index (if there's any) on `DATUM_OSIGURANJA` (or you should create a function-based index).

The right option is to change column's datatype. Always store dates into `DATE` datatype column. Never store it as `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: this solution is not Index friendly since to convert `datum_osiguranja` to date... and no need to create index based function if OP applies my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your date column is string kind. You need to convert your column to date and then convert back to varchar2

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB EVP_1 WHERE 
EVP_1.OIB_OSIGURANIK = ? 
AND DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE(DATUM_OSIGURANJA))) FROM 
EVP_V_KASKO_ZB"
WHERE OIB_OSIGURANIK = EVP_1.OIB_OSIGURANIK)
```